# Reverse the order of only certain Div children elements

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can you reverse the order of only certain div's children elements with pure CSS?

For example:

I want

```
<div id="parent">
    <a>A</a>
    <a>B</a>
    <a>C</a>
    <a>D</a>
    <div id="sub-child">
        <a>X</a>
        <a>Y</a>
        <a>Z</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

to be displayed as:

D

C

B

A

X

Y

Z

I tried:

```
#parent {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse; 
}
```

However, It is reversing everything inside parent (Not giving desired result)

Comment: There is an error on your provided html example.

Comment: Is typo error, `<a>D</div>` is `<a>D</a></div>`

Comment: Not it all ;-) An `</a>`is still missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. apply `display: flex` on both `#parent` and `#sub-child`;
2. give `flex-direction: column-reverse` for the `#parent` and `flex-direction: column` for `#sub-child`;
3. use a negative `order` for `#sub-child` so to keep that node at the bottom

```css
#parent {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#sub-child {
  order: -1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <a>A</a>
    <a>B</a>
    <a>C</a>
    <a>D</a>
    <div id="sub-child">
      <a>X</a>
      <a>Y</a>
      <a>Z</a>
    </div>
</div>
```